# mysql trigger get column value by vaiable

Tags: mysql, sql

In this mysql trigger after create I have:

```
@var = 'column_name_of_new_object'
```

How can i get `NEW.@var? Like eval` in javascript.

Comment: elaborate it little bit more

Comment: What are you talking about?  With a trigger, you would create a new row.  It's not an object.  The columns are already defined for the table you attached the trigger to.  If you don't use clear terminology, and clear examples, your question will need to be closed.

Comment: I have table **people** and writing trigger for after create. After create people row I need to get one of the column value of people row(NEW) to insert into another table. But that column name not fixed. I have some logic. In that logic i will get any column of people row. Now i have NEW object and also column name in one variable say @var=logic(). logic() func will return some string which is a column name in people. Now how do i get the value of that column from NEW object.

Answer (score 1):

In general, making an identifier based on a variable requires that you use dynamic SQL, like with PREPARE and EXECUTE.

But you can't use dynamic SQL inside a trigger.

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
    -> FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    -> DECLARE col VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'mytimestamp';
    -> SET @sql = CONCAT('SET NEW.', col , ' = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())');
    -> PREPARE st FROM @sql;
    -> EXECUTE st;
    -> END;;

ERROR 1336 (0A000): Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger
```

You can't do this, and I think you would be hard pressed to come up with a reason to do so.

---

Your comment above:

> I need to get one of the column value of people row(NEW) to insert into another table. But that column name not fixed.

This is not correct—the columns of a table *are* fixed. If you change the column name, you must change your trigger too.

Comment: I agree. But I have to get value from NEW.

Comment: I have **data** table which will have junk data without index. Now i have one mapping table which will have some indexed column names. Now I have to insert those indexed columns to another table.

Comment: Nevertheless, you can't do dynamic SQL inside a trigger.